# insert repeated when i execute programm

Tags: java

Hi i have code java swing to insert 2 lines in tables sql
and i insert in table 2 jtextfields that i set in frame
So i want don't insert line if i set the same text in jTextfields

this is the code:

```
Connection conn = null;
     Statement stmt = null;
    try{
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+db, "root", "123456");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO router(hostname,address,version)VALUES('Edge 01','"+jTextField1.getText()+"','2700')" )  ;
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO router(hostname,address,version) VALUES('Edge 02','"+jTextField2.getText()+"','2700)" )  ;
stmt.close();
conn.close();

    }
        catch(SQLException ek){
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You're looking for the wonders of the `if` statement.  (with a sprinkling of string comparison)

Comment: In other words, what have you tried? What problem did you have?

Comment: Looks like you're mates with [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: so i set text in 2 jtexfield and this i use it in Insert to add this strings intables but when i execute every time i want if the text it's the same that it's in table don't add them else add them

Comment: Boris the Spider what did u say are u crazy ?

Comment: Do a query first to check, what's the trouble? And it's a link to an xkcd cartoon illustrating SQL injection.

Comment: Okey im sorry because i don't understand very well im so so sorry thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible options:

1. Try retrieving the record using select statement and insert only when if select results into ZERO records.
2. Create a unique key/index on the database table columns and let the inserts trigger. Insert will fail in case of duplicates but you need handle the exceptions (duplicate/unique).

If possible, apply both the steps together otherwise select one of the steps better suiting your other business scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you **never**, **ever**, build queries at `String`s. Use a `PreparedStatement`.

Now, with that out of the way. You need to first query the database to see if it contains the desired value, if it doesn't insert it.

Move this logic into a separate method for clarity. And always close resources in a `finally` block, otherwise you get a memory leak if there is an `Exception`. I have used the Java 7 try-with-resources construct.

```
public boolean insertIfNotPresent(final Connection con, final String value) throws SQLException {
    final String checkQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM router where hostname='Edge 01' and version=2700 and address=?";
    try (final PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(checkQuery)) {
        statement.setString(1, value);
        try (final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
            if (resultSet.next() && resultSet.getInt(1) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    final String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO router SET hostname='Edge 01', version=2700, address=?";
    try (final PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery)) {
        statement.setString(1, value);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
    return true;
}
```

So the first query, `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`, counts rows matching the criteria. If there is already something in the database we return `false`.

The second query does the insert if we didn't return `false` from the first part. The method returns `true` in this case.

As an example in the above code, something like the following would work

```
try(final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+db, "root", "123456")) {
    insertIfNotPresent(conn, jTextField1.getText());
    insertIfNotPresent(conn, jTextField2.getText());
}
```

Comment: im working in netbeans swing how can i insert this code in button code

Comment: I have added a simple example. If you don't know how to use methods then I suggest you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: yes im reading and testing but i have some errors

Comment: Thank's a lot Boris the Spider it's correct and it worked thank you have a nice day

Comment: Sorry but i do 2 insert corresponded to the two jtextfield jtextfield1-edge 01 and jtextfield2_egde 02 but it's repeated