# Insert if not exists into table

Tags: java, jdbc

I want do an INSERT into table IF NOT EXISTS

So I have 2 `JTextField`s and I want add the variables that i st into `JTextfield`s int table but in condition that they are not exists in table

This is the code and it gives me errors about the query:

```
try{
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+db, "root", "123456");
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       stmt.executeUpdate(
           "insert into router (edge01,edge02)\n" +
           "Select edge01, edge02 " +
           "Where not exists(select * from router " +
                            "where edge01='" + jTextField1.getText() +
                              "' and edge02='" + jTextField2.getText() + "')");
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(bdd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Error:

`SEVERE: null

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Where not exists(select * from router where edge01='fffffffff' and edge02='fffff' at line 2`

Comment: You already got your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17219357/1065197 IMO I would choose the latter.

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in you query

```
try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+db, "root", "123456");
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       stmt.executeUpdate("insert into router (edge01,edge02)\n" +
" Select edge01,edge02 Where <Some unique Field> not exists in(select "<Some unique Field>" from router where edge01='"+jTextField1.getText()+"' and edge02='"+jTextField2.getText()+"')");

}          catch (SQLException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(bdd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
```

Comment: stmt.executeUpdate("insert into router (edge01,edge02) Select edge01,edge02 Where <Some unique Field> not exists in(select "<Some unique Field>" from router where edge01='"+jTextField1.getText()+"' and edge02='"+jTextField2.getText()+"')");
 this is my query why this line red about it

Comment: in your sub query not to use select * but instead use select edge01 and then compare where edge01 not exist in

Comment: i test it bu always this Error : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where <Some unique Field> not exists in(select <Some unique Field> from router w' at line 2

Comment: ("insert into router (edge01,edge02)\n" +
" Select edge01,edge02 where <Some unique Field> not exists in(select <Some unique Field> from router where edge01='"+jTextField1.getText()+"' and edge02='"+jTextField2.getText()+"')");     BUT DOSENT WORK

Comment: <some unique field> means you need to enter fields dont direct copy and paste .

Comment: i do it and the same error about wher not exists int : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where edge01 not exists in(select edge01 from router where edge01='1' and edge02' at line 2

Comment: Select edge01,edge02 Where not exists here you need to define table rest of your code is fine

Answer (score 0):

First select the data to check if data is exist: 'using select * from router'. If it return no data then insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query instead:

```
insert into router (edge01,edge02)
 select edge01,edge02 from router where edge01 not in(select edge01 from router where    
       edge01='"+jTextField1.getText()+"' and edge02='"+jTextField2.getText()+"')"
```

Comment: it gives me Any error but it's not added in table tha table contains 3 columns and the thirt column i want always add the number 2700 and the first and second columns they are added from the jTextfields